# Controller fails to pass instance variables into view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, instance-variables

In my home page I iterate over collections of objects, and for each object I render its attributes in a table row. There are four collections of objects, defined as instance variables in my controller, all making Guard (according to the used method) raising one of the following errors:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass
```

The code in my application view raising the above errors is:

```
<table class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Rank </th>
      <th> Gamer </th>
      <th> Points </th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <% @atp_gamers.each_with_index do |gamer, index| %>
     <tr>
       <td class="index"> <%= index+1 %> </td>
       <td class="gamer"> <%= gamer.name %> </td>
       <td class="atppoints"> <%= gamer.atpscore %> </td>
     </tr>
   <% end %>
     <tr class="current-user">
       <td> <%= @atp_gamers.to_a.index(current_user) + 1 %> </td>
       <td> <%= current_user.name %> </td>
       <td> <%= current_user.atpscore %> </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<table class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Year </th>
      <th> Champion </th>
      <th> Points </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% if @atp_champions.any? %>
      <% @atp_champions.each do |champion| %>
        <tr>
          <td class="year"> <%= champion.created_at.year %> </td>
          <td class="winnername"> <%= champion.name %> </td>
          <td class="winnerpoints"> <%= champion.points %> </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The above code is part of a partial (named `_gamers_home.html.erb`) rendered in the original home page:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <% if current_user.gamer? %>
    <%= render 'static_pages/gamers_home' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'static_pages/non_gamers_home' %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'static_pages/non_logged_in_home' %>
<% end %>
```

The `logged_in?` method is defined as `!current_user.nil?`

The instance variables that result nil are: `@atp_gamers`, `@wta_gamers`, `@atp_champions` and `@wta_champions`, defined in the controller as follows:

```
  def home
    if logged_in? && !current_user.gamer?
      ...l
    elsif logged_in? && current_user.gamer?
      @gamers = User.where(gamer: true)
      @atp_gamers = @gamers.order(atpscore: :desc).limit(50)
      @wta_gamers = @gamers.order(wtascore: :desc).limit(50)
      @atp_champions = AtpChampion.all
      @wta_champions = WtaChampion.all
      ...
    end
  end
```

The first instance variable raising the error (`each_with_index' for nil:NilClass`) is `@atp_gamers`. In view I tried to change it with its explicit value, that is `User.where(gamer: true).order(atpscore: :desc).limit(50)`, and the respective code is accepted. After this change, Guard raises an error for `@atp_champions`.

With rails console `@atp_gamers` and `@wta_gamers` are not empty, returning 50 records out of 100 users. `@atp_champions` and `@wta_champions` are not nil, but empty arrays.

I suspect that this might be an issue raised only by Guard, because the rails server succeeds in rendering the view.

Comment: The controller doesn't fail to pass anything, if it's `nil` in the view it's `nil` in the controller. Is `logged_in?` always returning false perhaps?

Comment: There is a home page dedicated to gamers, which I currently working on, and one dedicated to non-gamers. I updated the original message with this info. Both pages use the logged_in? method. The non-gamers home page works as expected, logged_in? returning true.

Comment: @Iceman These variables are defined in the controller. Also, if in the view I change them with their explicit full-length value, no error is raised. So, as far as I understand, their value (not nil) fails to arrive into view.

Comment: They are `nil` in the controller if it's `nil` in the view, that is quite simple. You just have to find out why it's `nil`, using eliminations. Maybe remove all lines from both the view and the controller and track down the error that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
def home
  if logged_in?  # delete this line
  ...
  end  # delete this line
end
```

Delete the `if logged_in?`, and see what happens.

Maybe you have to use `before_action :logged_in_user, only :home` in controller and define the `logged_in_user` method as private method.

If non-logged-in users also allowed to access the home action, you need to use if statement erb in the view. Like,

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <% @atp_gamers.each_with_index do |gamer, index| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

--UPDATE--

Maybe, it needs to toss variables to the partial.

Replace

```
<%= render 'static_pages/gamers_home' %>
```

to

```
<%= render partial: 'static_pages/gamers_home', locals: {atg_gamers: @atp_gamers, wta_gamers: @wta_gamers, atp_champions: @atp_champions, wta_champions, @wta_champions} %>
```

and, replace the `@atp_gamers`, `@wta_gamers`, `@atp_champions`, `@wta_champions` in the partial to `atp_gamers`, `wta_gamers`, `atp_champions`, `wta_champions`.

Try and see what happens.

Comment: I receive the following error: ActionView::Template::Error: undefined local variable or method `atp_gamers' for #<#<Class:0x00000007cbdd40>:0x0000000784d4b8>
        Did you mean?  @atp_gamers

Comment: Set `<%= render partial: 'static_pages/gamers_home',  locals: {test_local_variable: "Successfully got variable!"} %>` in view. And delete all the codes in '_gamers_home.html.erb' (of course u need backup) and remain only `<%= test_local_variable %>`. If the page can display "Successfully got variable!" after that, the app itself is working correctly.